# How to check Key/Value exists in List of Dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

For given a dictionary of list of dictionary below, I would like to check if key value `"url": "/Province/?ID=83"` exist in a list of dictionary or not.

```
data = {
          "current_page": 1,
          "data": [
              {
                  "columns": [
                      {
                          "key": "ID",
                          "value": "83"
                      },
                      {
                          "key": "Description",
                          "value": "Test Curring"
                      },
                      {
                          "key": "LocalDescription",
                          "value": "tests curring"
                      }
                  ],
                  "important": [
                      {
                          "key": "ID",
                          "value": "83"
                      },
                      {
                          "key": "Description",
                          "value": "Test Curring"
                      },
                      {
                          "key": "LocalDescription",
                          "value": "tests curring"
                      }
                  ],
                  "url": "/Province/?ID=83"
              },
              {
                  "columns": [
                      {
                          "key": "ID",
                          "value": "82"
                      },
                      {
                          "key": "Description",
                          "value": "Test 81 Description"
                      },
                      {
                          "key": "LocalDescription",
                          "value": "Local Test Description"
                      }
                  ],
                  "important": [
                      {
                          "key": "ID",
                          "value": "82"
                      },
                      {
                          "key": "Description",
                          "value": "Test 81 Description"
                      },
                      {
                          "key": "LocalDescription",
                          "value": "Local Test Description"
                      }
                  ],
                  "url": "/Province/?ID=82"
              },
          ]
      }
```

I know it exist, how can I check to return `True` or `False` for its existence?

I tried:

```
list_data = data.get('data')

index = 0
for item in list_data:
  url = item[0].get('url')
  index += 1
  print 'url: ',url
```

However, I got error:

```
    url = item[0].get('url')
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: @ScottHunter, thanks for pointing out. I have edited to add my tried already. Could you check it? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works by gathering `url` of each item in `data['data']` and seeing if the desired value is in it; it assumes every item in `data['data']` has a `url` element.

```
"/Province/?ID=83" in [x['url'] for x in data['data']]
```

Comment: It has been working well, thanks so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the schema of `data` is consistent, you can try this:
It will return `True` if `key:value` exist in data, else it will return `False`.

```
  def check(data, key, value):
      for i in data['data']:
        try:
          if(i[key]==value): return True
        except:
          pass
      return False
```